# openOrCreateDatabase SQLite Error

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite

I am a new Android Developer and I am making an app which stores some expiration dates.

**The problem:** When I want to create a **new Date** from the input of the user, SQLite is calling a null **openOrCreateDatabase()** method.

If you have any feedback or need any other class, please dont hesitate to indulge me !

**LogCat**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
                  at tech.destinum.recorderis.DB.DBHelper.createDate(DBHelper.java:131)
                  at tech.destinum.recorderis.adapters.FormAdapter$1.onClick(FormAdapter.java:70)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**DBHelper**

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private final static String DB_NAME = "recorderis";
private final static int DB_VERSION = 1;

public final static String TABLE_USERS = "users";
public final static String USERS_COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public final static String USERS_COLUMN_NAME = "name";
public final static String USERS_COLUMN_CELLPHONE = "cellphone";
public final static String USERS_COLUMN_FIJO = "fijo";
public final static String USERS_COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
public final static String USERS_COLUMN_PREMIUM = "premium";

public final static String TABLE_DATES = "dates";
public final static String DATES_COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public final static String DATES_COLUMN_NAME = "name";
public final static String DATES_COLUMN_DATE = "date";
public final static String DATES_COLUMN_USER_ID = "user_id";


public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String users = String.format("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USERS + "("
                    + USERS_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + USERS_COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, "
                    + USERS_COLUMN_CELLPHONE + " INTEGER, "
                    + USERS_COLUMN_FIJO + " INTEGER, "
                    + USERS_COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT, "
                    + USERS_COLUMN_PREMIUM + ")", TABLE_USERS, USERS_COLUMN_ID, USERS_COLUMN_NAME,
            USERS_COLUMN_CELLPHONE, USERS_COLUMN_FIJO, USERS_COLUMN_EMAIL, USERS_COLUMN_PREMIUM);

    String dates = String.format("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_DATES + "("
                    + DATES_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + DATES_COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, "
                    + DATES_COLUMN_DATE + " DATE, "
                    + DATES_COLUMN_USER_ID + " LONG)", TABLE_DATES, DATES_COLUMN_ID, DATES_COLUMN_NAME, DATES_COLUMN_DATE,
            DATES_COLUMN_USER_ID);

    try {
        db.execSQL(users);
        db.execSQL(dates);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USERS);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_DATES);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void createNewUser(String name, int cell, int fijo, String email, String premium){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(USERS_COLUMN_NAME, name);
    values.put(USERS_COLUMN_CELLPHONE, cell);
    values.put(USERS_COLUMN_FIJO, fijo);
    values.put(USERS_COLUMN_EMAIL, email);
    values.put(USERS_COLUMN_PREMIUM, premium);
    db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_USERS, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
    db.close();
}

public void createDate(String name, String date, long user_id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DATES_COLUMN_NAME, name);
    values.put(DATES_COLUMN_DATE, date);
    values.put(DATES_COLUMN_USER_ID, user_id);
    db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_DATES, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
    db.close();
}
```

}

**FormAdapter**

```
public class FormAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FormAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public static final String FORM_PREFERENCES = "FormPreferences";
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<Document> mDocuments;
private DBHelper mDBHelper;

public FormAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Document> mDocuments) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mDocuments = mDocuments;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.format_form, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Document document = mDocuments.get(position);
    mDBHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);

    holder.mTitle.setText(document.getName());
    holder.mTitleExpanded.setText(document.getName());
    holder.mEditText.setTag(R.id.date_et, position);
    holder.mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = (int) holder.mEditText.getTag(R.id.date_et);
            Log.d("pos", String.valueOf(position));

            SharedPreferences mSP = v.getContext().getSharedPreferences(FORM_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mSP.edit();

            String data = holder.mEditText.getText().toString();

            switch (position){
                case 0:


                    mDBHelper.createDate(v.getContext().getString(R.string.doc_soat), data, document.getId());
                    Log.d("SOAT", data);
                    mEditor.putString("soat", data);
                    mEditor.commit();

                    break;
                case 1:

                    mDBHelper.createDate(v.getContext().getString(R.string.doc_rtm), data, document.getId());

                    Log.d("RTM", data);
                    mEditor.putString("rtm", data);
                    mEditor.commit();

                    break;
                case 2:

                    mDBHelper.createDate(v.getContext().getString(R.string.doc_str), data, document.getId());

                    Log.d("SRC", data);
                    mEditor.putString("src", data);
                    mEditor.commit();

                    break;
                case 3:

                    mDBHelper.createDate(v.getContext().getString(R.string.doc_src), data, document.getId());

                    Log.d("STR", data);
                    mEditor.putString("str", data);
                    mEditor.commit();

                    break;
                case 4:

                    mDBHelper.createDate(v.getContext().getString(R.string.doc_tao), data, document.getId());

                    Log.d("TO", data);
                    mEditor.putString("to", data);
                    mEditor.commit();

                    break;
            }

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDocuments != null ? mDocuments.size(): 0;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    public TextView mTitle, mTitleExpanded;
    public Button mButton;
    public EditText mEditText;
    public ImageView mImageView;

    private int originalHeight = 0;
    private boolean isViewExpanded = false;
    private ConstraintLayout mConstraintLayout;
    private DateWatcher mDateWatcher;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);

        mConstraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.expanded);
        mTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name_title_tv);
        mTitleExpanded = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name_title_tv_expanded);
        mButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        mEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.date_et);
        mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView_up);

        mDateWatcher = new DateWatcher(mEditText);
        mEditText.addTextChangedListener(mDateWatcher);

        if (isViewExpanded == false) {
            // Set Views to View.GONE and .setEnabled(false)
            mConstraintLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mConstraintLayout.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        // If the originalHeight is 0 then find the height of the View being used 
        // This would be the height of the ConstraintLayout
        if (originalHeight == 0) {
            originalHeight = v.getHeight();
        }

        // Declare a ValueAnimator object
        ValueAnimator valueAnimator;
        if (!isViewExpanded) {
            mTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mTitle.setEnabled(false);
            mImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mConstraintLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mConstraintLayout.setEnabled(true);
            isViewExpanded = true;
            valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(originalHeight, originalHeight + (int) (originalHeight)); // These values in this method can be changed to expand however much you like
        } else {
            isViewExpanded = false;
            valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(originalHeight + (int) (originalHeight), originalHeight);

            Animation a = new AlphaAnimation(1.00f, 0.00f); // Fade out

            a.setDuration(200);
            // Set a listener to the animation and configure onAnimationEnd
            a.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    mTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mTitle.setEnabled(true);
                    mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mConstraintLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mConstraintLayout.setEnabled(false);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });

            // Set the animation on the custom view
            mConstraintLayout.startAnimation(a);
        }
        valueAnimator.setDuration(200);
        valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                Integer value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                v.getLayoutParams().height = value.intValue();
                v.requestLayout();
            }
        });


        valueAnimator.start();

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is given right in the error message: within your db helper it is calling Context.openOrCreateDb on a null reference to Context.  This implies that the mContext passed to the mDBHelper constructor is null, which in turn implies that the mContext supplied to the FormAdapter constructor is null.